# How to copy a cell to blank cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an item number in Column A and location quantities in Column C. Many times the location quantity will be on multiple lines (multiple locations). When this happens, the item number is on the first line, but the multiple location lines are left blank in Column A. Is there a way to copy the cell down, until Column A has a different value, then copy the new value down until it runs into another different value, so on and so on?

```
0V2L   2
       3
       1
DY29   5
       3
0VGE   1
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
0V2L   2
0V2L   3
0V2L   1
DY29   5
DY29   3
0VGE   1
```

Comment: Clever instructions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762340/excel-data-entry-help

Comment: That works well. How do I close this now?

Comment: Typically, links to help are more suitable for comments than answers.  I'd be happy to post this as an answer, though, if you want to accept it and no one objects.

Comment: It worked for me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment above:

Clever instructions can be found here:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/3762340/excel-data-entry-help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762340/excel-data-entry-help)